# Constant quantity associated to symmetry

Tags: conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism

I'm attending a subject in theoretical mechanics and we saw this fact that bugged me a little. It's by the way referenced in:

> John R Cary, *Lie transform perturbation theory for Hamiltonian systems.*  Physics Reports 79, 1981.

They first state that a function $w(z,t,\theta)$, being $z_i$ the phase space variables $1\leq i \leq 2n$, and $\theta$ some parameter, generates a symmetry for a hamiltonian if its time derivative doesn't depend on the $z_i$'s. ie:

$$\lbrace w,\mathcal {H} \rbrace + \frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t}=\phi(t,\theta)$$

for some function $\phi(t,\theta)$. ($\lbrace \cdot,\cdot \rbrace$ is the Poisson bracket.)

I can get that. Now, they say the conserved quantity associated to this is:

$$g=\omega-\int^t\phi(t',\theta)dt'$$
I don't really get this, as the integrand is the time derivative, and therefore the value of the integral is $\omega +C $ for any constant $C$, and $g$ is constant trivially. It's like saying that a constant is constant, isn't it?

Am I missing anything?

EDIT: What I am asking is if that result is correct or if it's just stating that if $\omega$ generates a family of continous canonical transformations that's a symmetry of $\mathcal H$, then the generator is conserved?

Comment: You are somehow uncomfortable with the fact that a constant is a constant?

Comment: @bechira I am uncomfortable with stating that as some kind of theorem. I'd expect some kind of relevant content, plus I know how Noether conserved charges come out from symmetries, and I was expecting to see a connection.